# Как закрыть всплывающее обучение на сайте Python + bs4 + request

Tags: python, requests, bs4

На сайте https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/ при первом входе( и когда пытаешься парсить) тебе предлагают пройти обучение, но я хочу сделать так чтобы когда я кидал запрос на сайт то этого не было( иначе нужная мне инфа не показывается) .По идее мне просто нужно нажать "Пропустить обучение" чтобы всё решилось, но я не знаю как это сделать с помощью request, а точнее не знаю какой запрос надо дать серверу чтобы сразу нажималось "Пропустить обучение".

Comment: Вот что он мне выдает

Comment: function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-15707457-7');</script><body style="height: 100%; width:100%;"><div id="app" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"></div><script src="static/js/manifest.f9c1ce6b2395b56421f5.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="static/js/vendor.32328c0bb8bc32439bb7.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="static/js/app.32849389c6145c4fe2eb.js" type="text/javascript"></script></body></html>